# test if two dom elements are equal in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, dom, element

Is there a way to test if two dom elements are exactly equal in Java?

What is the best way to test the equality between two elements in JUnit Testing. If there is a java method to test the equality between two dom elements, then perhaps I could use assertTrue over this java method. Would that work ?

Say I have two dom nodes, n1 and n2 I tried the following in junit test:

```
assertTrue(n1.isEqualNode(n2));
```

Please see the result of my test print statements

```
node n1 is: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><user trust="false"><userid>user</userid><password>70A0C520F974F76D994779C92326BEFFDECC344B</password><username>sony</username><organization>org</organization></user>

node n2 is: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><user trust="false">
  <userid>user</userid>
  <password>70A0C520F974F76D994779C92326BEFFDECC344B</password>
  <username>sony</username>
  <organization>org</organization>
</user>
```

This throws a java assertion error.

The nodes I used are exact replicates of each other with same child node lists and values.

Thanks,
Sony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XmlUnit http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/ for testing xml values.

Comment: @Jeff: I am using junit in eclipse for a number of reasons and I would like to continue using it unless there is no other way out. I am curious, what really is wrong with my approach. Thanks!

Comment: @sony. The isEqualNode method will compare node values character for character, so if one version has line breaks and tabs, they will not be equal. Also, XmlUnit is just an extension built on top of JUnit so it should integrate in with JUnit seamlessly.

Comment: Heartily recommend XmlUnit. I've used it many times to check xml data.

Comment: Hi, I downloaded XmlUnit 1.3. I am not sure how to proceed. I added xmlunit-1.3.jar file to my classpath through eclipse. I extended my junit test class to XMLTestCase. I used to run my junit tests using the command: "org.junit.runner.JUnitCore classname". If I try this now, I am getting the error: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError:. What command should I use to run the class with xml test case. Are there any other configuration steps that I missed? Thanks! –

Comment: I start a database session in a setUp() method annotated by @BeforeClass. This doesn't seem to work properly. Because, an assertTrue method which works in first test method seems to fail in the next test method. So, somehow the database connection seems to be lost.

Comment: @sony, to keep things simple, you don't need to extend XMLTestCase (in case this is breaking what you are doing). You can just use the XMLAssert class to make assertions on your xml.

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks ! XMLTestCase methods are compatible with Junit 3.x and not Junit 4.x. So, it ignores @BeforeClass and @AfterClass annotations of Junit 4.x. In this case, instead of extending the class to XMLTestCase using XMLAssert.assertXMLEquals(....) helps!

Answer (score 2):

As per the java doc: `public boolean isEqualNode(Node arg);`

> It tests whether two nodes are equal.
>   This method tests for equality of
>   nodes, not sameness (i.e., whether the
>   two nodes are references to the same
>   object) which can be tested with
>   Node.isSameNode(). **All nodes that are
>   the same will also be equal, though
>   the reverse may not be true.**

Open a debug session in your favorite IDE and check whether the object id of `n1` and `n2` in `n1.isEqualNode(n2)` is same or different.

If you are looking for same node then try using `public boolean isSameNode(Node other);`.